# Make user only input integer in scanner Java

Tags: java, input, integer

i have some problems here.
I want to user only can input as an integer. I have tried by many code, but still doesn't work. Btw, this is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test { 
  public static void main (String []args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = scan.nextInt();
  }
}
```

When error, the message will shown as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at test.main(test.java:6)
```

Please help me (Beginner Programmer);

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://ideone.com/IogIpV)

Comment: Me neither. java -version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("Input is not a number.");
      scan.nextLine();
    }
    int number = scan.nextInt();
  }
```

This code will check if the input is an Integer, if it is then it will continue.

Comment: i like this one. easy, short and precise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number -> ");
            String input = sc.next();
            int intInputValue = 0;
            try {
                intInputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
                System.out.println("This is not a number");
            }
        }
    }
```

This program will end when the user enter a integer input value.

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Such an error only occurs if the user did not enter an integer.For such a situation, you could create a `try-catch` block, that catches the exception, like this:

```
String input = sc.next();
int number = 0;
try {
   number = Integer.valueOf(input);
} catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
   System.out.println("Invalid input!");
}
```

To optimize the solution even more, put this all in a loop, and break out of it in the `try-block`, and keep polling for input if the user enters a bad number.